# Animated hiding of one of 2 side by side divs gives jerky motion to the other div

Tags: jquery-ui

I have 2 divs stacked side by side. Using jQueryUI, I hide one of the divs using slide animation, but the other div gets resized without the animation. 
Clicking on the button hides right div, but left div does not animate.

EDIT: On clicking the button, the right(blue) div animates and hides towards right. But the left(yellow) div does not change size. It then resets to 100% width without any sliding animation. Reverse happens when showing right div.
What I need is that left div animates resize along with the animation of the right div.

Is there a way to give the resizing an animation as well?
HTML:

```
<div class="right">right content</div>
<div class="left">
  left content
  <button onclick="toggle()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function toggle() {
  if($(".right").is(":visible")) {
            $('.right').hide("slide", {
                direction : "right"
            }, 500);
  } else {
            $('.right').show("slide", {
                direction : "right"
            }, 500);
  }
}
```

Codepen link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNaNpe

Comment: can't understand what you want. please explain

Comment: @Atula, sorry for the unclear post. I have edited the original post to better clarify the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
.left {
height: 100%;
float: none; 
overflow: hidden;
position:fixed;
}
```

and

```
$(".left").css("width","100%");
$(".right").hide();
function toggle() {
  if($(".right").is(":visible")) {
            $('.right').hide("slide", {
                direction : "right"
            });
 $(".left").animate({'width': '100%'}); 
  } else {
            $('.right').show("slide", {
                direction : "right"
            });
       $(".left").animate({'width': '40%'});

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but was not able to achieve the desired result. Could you please edit the pen with your solution?

Comment: try http://codepen.io/Atula/pen/RaYZgz?editors=0010. But this is showing a white page on my side, check  on your side too.

Comment: if you add background: #ff9 to body then the white page issue will get solve.

Comment: Thanks Atula for your work. But I noticed that when the blue div is sliding in or our, the contents of the yellow div are hidden. This is also what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Atula/pen/RaYZgz?editors=0100. If it works then don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Hi Atula, I appreciate the effort you put in but this is not what I want. I need that text should also not flicker on the first div.

Comment: well its working nice on my side. Don't know why it is flickering on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:
https://codepen.io/MandeepSingh/pen/mEkJKY

In my codepen, I set the width of the right(blue) div to "auto" and animate the width of the left div on button click. This moves the blue div to the extreme right (by animation). When the button is clicked again, I just animate the width of the yellow div back from 100% to its initial size.

I think you did not want the contents of the div to be hidden during the animation so I have put in some junk text in both the divs so that you can see the contents moving along with the resizing divs.

One last thing, I have kept my code as close to yours but you can avoid using the hide(), show() functions by using a flag variable to toggle the animation on button click.

Here's the code...

HTML:

```
<div id="left"> left content
  <button onclick="toggle()">Click Me</button>
  <br>
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, 
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, 
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, 
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam
</div>

<div id="right">right content
<br><br>
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, 
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, 
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, 
  Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam, Agdam chagdm bagdam dagdam
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:calibri;
}

#right {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    background: #9ff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
    height: 100%;
    float: left; 
    width: 40%;
    background: #ff9;
}
```

JS:

```
function toggle()
{
    if($("#right").is(":visible")) 
    {
            $('#left').animate({"width":"100%" }, 3000, function(){
                $("#right").hide();
            });
    } 
    else 
    {
            $('#right').show();
            $('#left').animate({"width":"40%"}, 3000);  
    }
}
```

-OR- use this JS if you want to avoid hide() and show():

```
var flag = 0; 

function toggle()
{
    if(flag == 0) 
    {
            $('#left').animate({"width":"100%" }, 3000);
            flag = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
            $('#left').animate({"width":"40%"}, 3000);
            flag = 0;   
    }
}
```

As a plus, you don't have to use Jquery UI for this animation.